# GridView lookups displaying as "id;#value"

Tags: lookup-column, gridview, splistitemcollection

I am using an ASP.net gridview. The datasource is SPList.Items.GetDataTable().

The gridview is working fine; however, lookup and multilookup columns display as "id;#value". Is there any way to just show the value?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved this issue:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Members">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# RemoveCharacters(Eval("CampaignMembers").ToString())%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Make sure declare `using System.Text.RegularExpression;`:

```
protected string RemoveCharacters(object String)
{
    string s1 = String.ToString();
    string newString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"#[\d-];", string.Empty);
    newString = Regex.Replace(newString, "#", " ");
    return newString.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use SPBoundField in your gridview instead of BoundField

Comment: Okay. I tried SPGridView and spboundfield. I am still seeing the issue with lookupMulti where id;#value is showing when I have multiple values selected in the lookupmulti column.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [SPFieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx) (for a single lookup) and [SPFieldLookupValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx) (for a multi-lookup) to parse the field values using SharePoint's built-in methods for processing them.

Here is a revised version of your function for single lookups:

```
protected string RemoveCharacters(string fieldValue)
{
    SPFieldLookupValue value = new SPFieldLookupValue(fieldValue);
    return value.LookupValue;
}
```

I've also turned the parameter into a `string` since your XML passes one in.

Details on processing multiple lookups (and more) can be found in my blog article:

[Easily accessing Lookup and User fields](http://tsstsst.com/?p=44)