# Binding User to SPGridview

Tags: spgridview, spfielduser

I have an SPGridview and I made a CAML Query to get the modifier of a document. When I bind it to the SPGridview with a SPBoundfield the value is displayed like this:

> 1;#HANSEVIS13\sschindler

All I want is that this field should be like a Sharepoint Standard SPFieldUser. How would I achieve this?

Comment: I believe this may be very closely related: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17920/binding-user-to-spgridview

Comment: Circular reference? :)

Comment: @Stuart: So "closely related" = the same? haha :)

Comment: @Kit: Haha! Oops! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/7375/1529 Is the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @Rob: I did actually click that a couple times, thinking "Huh?" before I realised...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I didn't ry them but they seem very helpful.

I solved it with an Templatefield too but created a class and used a Linkbutton. Here's the code:

```
   public class TemplatedUserControl : ITemplate
   {
    private string loginName;
    private string displayName;

    public TemplatedUserControl(string loginName, string displayName)
    {
        this.loginName = loginName;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        LinkButton referUser = new LinkButton();
        referUser.DataBinding += new EventHandler(referUser_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(referUser);
    }

    private void referUser_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton referUser = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)referUser.NamingContainer;
        SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[userloginName]
        // Do something with the user
    }
```